# Migrated questions don't show a "last activity" status in the questions list

Tags: bug, migration, migrated-questions, last-activity

This is almost certainly not important enough to unleash the programmers immediately, but I thought I would add it for posterity, and because someone was kind enough to [report it](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3364/not-showing-question-action-on-main-page) on a site meta.

When a question is migrated inside the network, it appears that the question shows up on the main page without detailing what the activity is

[image]

The question indicated above with a delightful freehand red ellipsoid should have probably said

> *migrated* 26 minutes ago

in order to follow the pattern of other actions.

Comment: Was it really migrated at then, or is it just the asking date/time?

Comment: Im *fairly* sure it was the time it was migrated in.

Comment: Okay, just wondered.

Answer (score 5):

As a counterproposal to how this should be fixed...

"*migrated* (x) minutes ago" is slightly ambiguous. It might be better served if this was reworded to be "migrated here (x) minutes ago" to better relay that a question was brought here from elsewhere.

Here's a screenshot/mockup of how this would appear, taken from a list of recently active Meta SO questions:

[image: Recent activity event text changed to "migrated here," freehand red circled]