# When using search and sorting by activity, user action is sometimes missing

Tags: support, bug, search, last-activity

On [Puzzling.SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) I used the [search](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=created%3A2023&searchOn=3) `created:2023` and sorted by Active, and it looks as though some of the posts have a missing action between the user and the time. [(The same bug as the one for migrated questions)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267234/migrated-questions-dont-show-a-last-activity-status-in-the-questions-list)

> [image]

The actions are displayed normally on the home page and when I switch the 'sort-by' to Newest or Relevance or Score.

- On 1, the last action was a non-OP [setting a bounty](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/120798/timeline#history_ab6436a7-fc50-4d13-8854-9aefbe57e337)
- On 2, the last action was the [question asker editing an answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/121034/revisions).
- On 3, the last action was someone [answering](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/121036/timeline#history_15b5e269-deb7-47c3-a73d-ea290e35f2ab)
- On 4, the last action was the asker [editing the question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/120744/timeline#history_94078ecf-28b8-4453-a270-8cdaf347a0e9)
- On 5, the last action was an editor [editing the tags](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/121032/timeline#history_6476cbf0-a86b-4825-9bcd-1e4a9c88eb63) (the page redirects to the duplicate, so you have to go to the linked questions)

I can't really find any rhyme or reason as to when it shows the action and when it doesn't, and [here's another screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2W9Vn.png) on [English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) with a different search query.

To get super meta about it, [here's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=%5Bbug%5D%20%5Blast-activity%5DActive&searchOn=3) the search I did on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) to look for duplicates, and you can see there that several of the results have the same issue.

What's going on? Is there a logic to the bug that I'm missing? And can it be fixed?

Comment: @Sonic why do u think it's definitely not a bug?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum - I don't mind the edit, but I wonder how necessary it really is to link the sites. (Not criticizing, just curious)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ The [tag:support] tag is for questions where the author isn't sure if something is a bug; see its extended tag wiki. I edited the tag to match the final paragraph of the question.